# Is it appropriate to advertise a pre-beta site to a beta or post beta site?

Tags: discussion, beta-sites, site-promotion

There are lots of times in english.SE that a question turns out to be language universal and not really specific to English. And language specific questions are not part of the linguistics.SE charter. What is the most appropriate way to

- advertise a pre-beta site into a beta or post beta site to increase committers (many who would obviously be interested)?
- repost to another beta/post beta site?

Comment: If it's pre-beta, non-committers can't access it. So there's no much use in advertising in that stage...

Comment: @KennyTM: I guess I don't really understand the process. Can't people choose to commit to a site? How else do you get more people to commit?

Comment: (If the process isn't modified,) People commit to a site *before* the private beta begins, and you can't commit afterwards.

Comment: Related: [Should I advertise a Beta site by posting on Metas of other related sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381005/335251)

Comment: @kennytm: In case anyone comes across this post now – this is no longer true. Anyone can join a private beta site as long as they have a link to it.

Answer (score 2):

If the other site is still in the formative (definition or commitment) phase, and you notice a potentially interested user, the best way to let them know on SE is in a **chat**. Sometimes, leaving a comment is appropriate, but this should be done very sparingly, as you'd essentially be spamming for the proposed site.

Other sites (proposed, beta or launched) often come up when discussing the topicality of a question. So watch for borderline questions whose **closing** is being discussed in comments, or clearly off-topic questions that would be appropriate for the site you're trying to pimp. If the site is beta or launched, **suggest a migration** that a moderator might carry out. You can also participate in topicality discussions on **meta** sites, or post on the “where can I ask questions that aren't X questions” meta thread (e.g. [SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254567/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-dont-fit-or-are-off-topic-for-stack-overflow); English doesn't seem to have one, you could create it).

Comment: Chat is not a good way to contact someone arbitrarily. A user has to have been in a particular chatroom no more than 24 hours before in order to '@' them. Is it possible to open a private chat with anybody unannounced, like a sort of 'direct message'?

Comment: @Mitch you can invite a user to a chat from their chat profile, but it's not private. Only mods can set up a private chat room.

Comment: @Mitch If someone doesn't hang around in chat, they're unlikely to welcome unsolicited contacts. This is by design.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Your suggestion was "to let them know ... in a chat" (presumably by Meta Andrew's just mentioned method) which assumes that they are not already in a chat and so you are suggesting an unsolicited contact. So which thing are you suggesting "Let them know in chat" as you say in your answer, or "don't make unsolicited contact" as you say here in your comment?

Comment: @Mitch Both. If they're open to unsolicited contact, let them know in chat. If they aren't open to unsolicited contact, do not contact them unsolicited.