# Should I advertise a Beta site by posting on Metas of other related sites?

Tags: discussion, per-site-meta, beta-sites, site-promotion

Our [Bioacoustics](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/) SE site has reached the beta stage. This multidisciplinary site encompasses many disciplines, and there are potential overlaps with other general SE sites.

I posted an "ad" in the meta sites of a couple of related SE sites during the Private Beta stage (see posts in [Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14140/new-bioacoustics-se-site-may-be-of-interest-to-you), [Sound Design](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1480/new-bioacoustics-se-site-may-be-of-interest-to-you), [Biology](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4309/new-bioacoustics-se-site-may-be-of-interest-to-you), [Signal processing](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1748/new-bioacoustics-se-site-may-be-of-interest-to-you), and [Engineering](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/652/new-bioacoustics-se-site-may-be-of-interest-to-you)), and more recently since we've reached the Public Beta ([Pets](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2409/new-se-site-about-animal-sounds-bioacoustics-that-could-be-of-interest-of-the)).

While these ad posts are not directly about the site where I posted, the goal is to advertise about the Bioacoustics site to sites which share similar interests so that they know it exists in case they have specific questions that would be more appropriate in our site than in theirs. And let's be honest, also to make our site known better and get more members.

In general, it has been well accepted (up-votes), but some people are reluctant. Is this a good practice to advertise the Beta sites? If not, what would be the process to do so? Is there any policy about this?

Comment: Such posts were well received in the past, e.g. [Beta Site: Materials Modeling](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12912/beta-site-materials-modeling)

Comment: Well - the understanding has been that to a significant extent, beta sites should be self sustaining - I vaguely recall there was a policy about this or migrations, but I can't find it

Comment: "*In general, it has been well accepted (up-votes) [...]*" the problem is, we don't know who upvoted them. It could even be the members from the beta site themselves with the help of the association bonus rep, thus not representing the voice of the target site.

Comment: Related: [Is it appropriate to advertise a pre-beta site to a beta or post beta site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87039/335251)

Answer (score 5):

Well - the understanding has been that to a significant extent, beta sites should be self sustaining. A successful site already has its community of experts and is able to attract them on their own. We discourage migrations from beta sites for this reason, and sites don't *generally* advertise on each other's meta. We do have 'proper' ways do do this, like community ads.

I think there's a few important things to consider here - is the cross advertising/pollination advantageous to both sides - a hypothetical "farming.se" would have more in common with pets than bioacoustics. I don't think we've generally had a policy on cross-site advertising on meta, cause we've not needed it. With promotional tools like this, it feels like it would have been appropriate to get a network wide policy first, and given the appropriate folks (community team, and the moderator and broader network community) a heads up and some degree of consensus first.

With lower meta participation in smaller communities - I don't think votes alone are a reliable indicator. In addition to what Meta Andrew T pointed out in the comments to the question - that the upvotes might not be reflective of the 'active' community of that site (and meta's a subset of this on most cases)

As such - I'd feel disinclined to support the use of meta posts to 'advertise' a beta community. It goes against the general requirement of a site getting to graduation mostly on its most merits and as its done, was done without any real input from the network as far as I can tell.

Comment: Not to mention such "advertisements" are off-topic on other meta sites.

Comment: To clarify, is that your view/opinion, or is that policy? (I don't mean that rudely at all, but if that _is_ policy, then I'll edit my answer to clearly state that what I said is incorrect and to listen to policy instead - otherwise, I'll keep it around and not crossed-out so people can give opinions and vote)

Comment: I'm a moderator here. I don't set policy network wide. I give opinions, based on what I know based on my experience on the network.